# Lucene phrase search

Tags: search, lucene, lucene.net

I have large text documents. Say, if I search for "computer m", then I want to get "computer monitor", "computer memory", and  "computer market share". How can I get matched phrases only?

Should I index files using ShingleAnalyzerWrapper?
Should I use SpellChecker for this purpose?

How can I do this?

Comment: Why are you assuming that "m" should match "monitor" or "memory"? Have you tried doing a wildcard search using "computer m*"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[org.apache.lucene.search.highlight.Highlighter](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_0/api/contrib-highlighter/org/apache/lucene/search/highlight/Highlighter.html) is used to extract the best-matching text from a found document.  Much like how Google will highlight (or display in bold) the matching text in your search results.

This blog entry that might help you get a start on it:
http://hrycan.com/2009/10/25/lucene-highlighter-howto/

Answer (score 0):

You can use [MultiPhraseQuery](https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/MultiPhraseQuery.html) for that.

Comment: Does this let me output "computer market share" for the input "computer share"?